# Can compiler optimize non-related commands to be executed with different cores?

Tags: c++, optimization, compiler-optimization

Compiler can change order of non-correlating commands in term of optimization.
Can it also optimize them silently to be executed in different cores?

For example:

```
...
for (...) 
{
    //...
    int a = a1+a2;
    int b = b1+b2;
    int c = c1+c2;
    int d = d1+d2;
    //...
}
...
```

May it happen that in terms of optimization not just order of execution may be changed, but also amount of cores? Does compiler have any restrictions in standard?

UPD: I'm not asking how to parallelize the code, I'm asking if it was not parallelized explicitly, can it still be parallelized by compiler?

Comment: Google about threads. But it is not up to the compiler to run another thread on another core, the OS choose which thread runs on which core.

Comment: @mch threads are nice way to parallelize explicitly, but if it wasn't done, can someone guarantee that commands will be executed within one core?
Or if compiler can change the order, may it force execution be parallel?

Comment: The compiler may (and in practice also often do) emit code that executes such operations in parallel on *one* core, a possibility that your question doesn't seem to consider at all

Comment: @harold or code that *would be* sequential on a 486, but is parallelised by hardware on a modern cpu

Comment: @harold I don't really understand how may it be in parallel on one core?

Comment: @Arkady instruction level parallelism and SIMD, a single core can do a lot of work in a cycle

Comment: @harold but performing in cycle is not performing in parallel?\

Comment: @Arkady if there are multiple things happening in the same cycle, then that's parallelism

Comment: @Arkady see [AVX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions) - e.g a single instruction that performs 8 adds on 8 pairs of floats

Comment: thank you for explanations & links about one-core parallelism, not as logical core supposed to work, but that's how real cores work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is more than meets the eyes here. Most likely the instructions (in your example) will end up being run in parallel, but it's not what you think.

There are many levels of hardware parallelism in a CPU, multiple cores being just the highest one <sup>1)</sup>. Inside a CPU core you have other levels of hardware parallelization that are mostly transparent <sup>2)</sup> (you don't control them via software and you don't actually see them, only maybe their side-effects sometimes). Pipelines, extra bus lanes, multiple ALUs (Arithmetic Logic Units) and FPUs (Floating Point Units) per core are some of them.

Different stages of your instructions will be run in parallel in the pipelines (modern x86 processors have over a dozen pipeline stages) and possibly different instructions will run in parallel in different ALUS (modern x86 CPUs have around 5 ALUs per core).

All this happens without the compiler doing anything <sup>2)</sup>. And it's free (given the hardware, it was not free to add this capabilities in the hardware). Executing the instructions in different cores is not free. Creating of different threads is costly. Moving the data to be available to other cores is costly. Synchronization to wait for the execution from other cores is costly. There is a lot of overhead associated with creating and synchronizing threads. It is just not worth it for small instructions like this. And the cases that would have a real benefit from multi-threading would involve an analysis that is way too complicated today so practically not feasible. Someday in the future will have compilers that will be able to identify that your serial algorithm is actually a sort and efficiently and correctly parallelize it. Until then we have to rely on language support, library support and/or developer support for parallelizing algorithms.

*<sup>1)</sup> well, actually hyper-threading is.*

<sup>2)</sup> As pointed by MSalters:

> modern compilers are very much aware of the various ALU's and will do
>   work to benefit from them. In particular, register assignments are
>   optimized so you don't have ALU's compete for the same register,
>   something which may not be apparent from the abstract sequential
>   model.

All this it indirectly influences the execution to benefit the hardware architecture, there are not explicit instructions or declarations.

Comment: To be honest, modern compilers are very much aware of the various ALU's and will do work to benefit from them. In particular, register assignments are optimized so you don't have ALU's compete for the same register, something which may not be apparent from the abstract sequential model.

Comment: Couldn't a compiler generate code to use the GPU for parallel computations, say if the computations are performed on array elements? Today one probably needs a different toolchain (CUDA, OpenMP) for that but there is no logical obstacle for a compiler proper, I think.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider not really no. An important part of GPU programming (if you want any sort of real life performance) is aligning and shuffling data, something that does not appear in the sequential model.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider and if the compiler gets smart enough to do that automatically on the GPU then the next question becomes couldn't a compiler generate code to upload the algorithm for cloud computation?

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider and then, if the compiler is smart enough to do all this from a sequential written algorithm, the next question becomes what do we need programmers for? At this point the compiler is basically an advanced AI capable of understanding algorithms.

Comment: @bolov this is a never ending quest for automation, including code optimization automation. An ai system, that you describe, still needs a programmer, to define the problem in some high-level formal-language. Think of a Frankenstein hybrid between CTL*, prolog, Haskell, and C++20 TMP with concepts, which is used to define a high level problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the compiler can do things in any order (including not doing them at all), so long as the observable behaviour generated matches what the observable behaviour of the code should be.   Assembly instructions, runtime, thread count, etc. are not observable behaviour.

I should add that it's unlikely a compiler would decide to do this without explicit instruction from the programmer to do so; even though the standard allows it, the compiler exists to help the programmer and randomly starting extra threads would be unexpected in many case

Comment: Thank you! That's known compiler possibilities, but can it also in case of observable behavior force execution of such instructions on 2 cores?

Comment: @Arkady "force" no, because the runtime environment **might not have** multiple cores, for instance on a virtualised OS with only one core assigned

Comment: @Caleth of course my question is valid just if environment have multiple cores ))